# Keyboard buffer issue with multi-byte characters (latin, diacritics) / dead keys

Tags: kernel, keyboard, xorg, xserver, dead-keys

I write in Spanish and sometimes I use diacritics (ie multi-byte chars) with dead keys, for example *"liberación"* ("liberation" in Spanish). Usually I don't have any problem, but when the GUI freeze or for any reason it can't handle more input, when the text shows up the diacritic char jump to the first position on the/a keyboard buffer, displaying something like ***"óliberacin"***, which is very annoying since occur very often while chatting or writing an email (easier to test: **aaaá**→**áaaa**). GNOME/Unity/Hardware couldn't be. Maybe a xserver or libinput or a kernel bug?

I have this problem since more than four years now, with several kernels, Ubuntu versions, hardware and versions of Firfeox and Chorme. I couldn't find any pattern neither something strange on `dmesg`/`journalctl`/`/var/log` files...

**Setup**: This happened to me since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fresh install, kernel 4.4.0-62-generic; and even recently with 18.04 and 4.15.0-134-generic, GNOME Shell 3.28.4.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_AR.UTF-8
[...]
$ im-config -l
ibus xim
$ im-config -m
default
missing
ibus 

ibus
$ env | grep "XMODIFIERS\|IM_"
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

How can I debug to find where the problem might be?

**Update 2021-01-23**

I didn't cross with this issue for a while, until today, typing from Desktop to Android ([GSconnect → KDE Connect Keyboard](https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/232#issuecomment-438657008)). The lagginess due to the info sent to the phone make the UI stall. This could be a good way to reproduce the issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see the same issue on Gnome Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @CapiEtheriel and all, please comment if you found a bug report somewhere. Is difficult to me to find where is the problem (browser/x/kernel/dm?).